# In Oracle "AS" alias not working

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Just want to know why Oracle not allowed "AS" alias in Query.
In My project all queries which i returned have alias keyword "AS".

For.eg;

```
Select t1.id,t2.name from Table1 As t1 ,Table2 t2 
on
  t1.id =t2.id
```

above Query run in all Server like PostgreSQL ,Microsoft SQL server but in Oracle its Not working
showing error "Command does not exists" because of alias "As".
If i remove then it will run.

just want to know why Oracle Server behave like this ? i want to run query using "AS"alias name.

Comment: "Why"? - because this is how Oracle implemented and documented it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2126863

Answer (score 5):

While Oracle allows you to use `AS` when defining column aliases, it doesn't allow you to use `AS` when defining table aliases. It's just how Oracle works.

Comment: Thankx for reply.but why Oracle behave like this as standard all server database allow "as" in table name  but only Oracle does not allow this.

Comment: To find the answer to that, you'd need to ask whoever it was that designed it like that in the first place - probably Larry himself. Good luck!

Comment: Looking at [the 11.2 doc ref provided by @a_horse_with_no_name above](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2126863) I note that the flashback_query_clause begins its second form with `AS` (i.e. `AS OF {SCN|TIMESTAMP} (expr)`). If `AS {tablealias}` was allowed it might make the parsing of statements trickier, so this may be part of the reason - along with "it's always been that way". The standards have various "levels" of compliance so that all software producers can claim compliance; I'm sure that all DB's are non-compliant to a degree. Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `as`(optional) for alias in column names but not for table. Using `as` in aliases is Microsoft standard, while ORACLE supports ANSI SQL syntax which using `as` in aliases is not a standard.

Comment: so its means Microsoft does not support ANSI SQL ?

Comment: None of the databases fully support ansi-sql they all do their own thing

Comment: Using `as` is **not** a "Microsoft Standard" - it's part of the **SQL** standard. **Not** using `AS` is _also_ part of the SQL standard, the keyword is defined as optional.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html#query%20specification) and this [this](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html#correlation%20specification) it should be part of the ISO SQL92. Maybe Oracle did not implement it because of backward compatibility.

In Oracle keywords like "AS", "JOIN", "COMMIT", "MODEL" still can be used as object names. So you can write something like:

```
select J.COMMIT AS
from JOIN J;
```

This will select column named "COMMIT" from table named "JOIN" and the column will be aliased to "AS".

Comment: No, it won't. I tried `select X.dummy as from dual X;` and it gave me 1 column named `dummy`. But you can write `select X.dummy "AS" from dual X;` giving you 1 column named `AS`.

Comment: ok. then is maybe was on older version. I just wanted illustrate, that in Oracle "as" might not be followed by any alias.